# SQL syntax error with DELETE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a website connected to a database managed by MySQL. These are the structures of tables *pagamenti* and *prenotazione*:

**Pagamenti**

[image: table_pagamenti]

**Prenotazione**

[image: table_prenotazione]

In my PHP code I want to delete a record from both tables using the field `IDPrenotazione`. I could use two different queries, as in the following code

```
$query1 = "DELETE FROM pagamenti WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID'";
$query2 = "DELETE FROM prenotazione WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID'";
```

but it would be much better if I use only one query. I've learned that in SQL language queries are separated by `;`, so I tried this code

```
$query = "DELETE FROM pagamenti WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID';
          DELETE FROM prenotazione WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID'";
```

but it returns this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM prenotazione WHERE IDPrenotazione='2017-0006'' at line 1
```

This is the complete code, with the execution

```
$query = "DELETE FROM pagamenti WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID';
          DELETE FROM prenotazione WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID'";
if (mysqli_query($connessione, $query))
{
    //code
}
else
{
    echo mysqli_error($connessione);
}
```

If I execute this code on phpMyAdmin it works as I want with no errors, so the query must be correct.

Why doesn't it work via PHP? How can I make it work?

Comment: show your query execution part of php code

Comment: It can be made to work, but personally I would stick with the 2 statements.  It's clearer and also less prone to other errors.

Comment: can't you run it like this: $query = "DELETE FROM pagamenti, prenotazione WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID'"; ?

Comment: *..Why doesn't it work via PHP?* For That, You Have To Share Your PHP Code. Right?

Comment: For multiple queries, try the [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Comment: @David no, it doesn't work this way

Comment: the default `mysqli_query` php function does not support multi queries, for security reasons I  suppose. `use mysqli_multi_query` instead if you really need to do that.

Comment: echo your $query before executing it and you will see more.

Comment: @mara6399 you cloud do it with joins: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

> The **mysqli_multi_query()** function performs one or more queries against
>   the database. The queries are separated with a semicolon.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM pagamenti WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID';DELETE FROM prenotazione WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID'";

mysqli_multi_query($connessione, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$query = "DELETE FROM pagamenti WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID';DELETE FROM prenotazione WHERE IDPrenotazione='$ID'";

mysqli_multi_query($connessione, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete data from two tables by **one query** but there must be an relation between two table.

Try like this :

```
 "DELETE `pagamenti`,`prenotazione ` from `pagamenti` LEFT JOIN `prenotazione ` on
 `pagamenti`.`id` = `prenotazione `.`pagementi_id` where `pagamenti`.`IDPrenotazione` = '". $ID."' 
  and `prenotazione`.`IDPrenotazione` = '" . $ID."'";
```

Here  `pagamenti`.`id` = `prenotazione`.`pagementi_id` is the relation you need to put here.

Its working for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already solved the problem using `mysqli_multi_query`

Comment: Okay that's good but if you think to delete two table data in one query then
you can  try this.It's  cool.